# How to animate the convex hull of a scatter plot

Tags: animation, matplotlib, convex-hull

I am trying to animate the convex hull of a scatter plot. The code below achieves this but the hull from previous time points is not deleted, resulting in each frame displaying the hull instead of the most current one.

How do I get the output to show the convex hull at each time point? So each frame is a new convex hull.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

visuals = [[],[],[]]

with open('Wide_Single_Timestamp.csv') as csvfile :
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
n=0
for row in readCSV :
    if n == 0 :
        n+=1
        continue
    visuals[0].append([float(row[3]),float(row[5]),float(row[7]),float(row[9]),float(row[11]),float(row[13]),float(row[15]),float(row[17]),float(row[19]),float(row[21]),float(row[23]),float(row[25]),float(row[27]),float(row[29]),float(row[31]),float(row[33]),float(row[35]),float(row[37]),float(row[39]),float(row[41]),float(row[43])])
    visuals[1].append([float(row[2]),float(row[4]),float(row[6]),float(row[8]),float(row[10]),float(row[12]),float(row[14]),float(row[16]),float(row[18]),float(row[20]),float(row[22]),float(row[24]),float(row[26]),float(row[28]),float(row[30]),float(row[32]),float(row[34]),float(row[36]),float(row[38]),float(row[40]),float(row[42])])
    visuals[2].append([1,2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))

X = np.array(visuals[0][0]) #X-Coordinates
Y = np.array(visuals[1][0]) #Y-Coordinates


scatterN = ax.scatter(X, Y, zorder = 2)   #Scatter Plot

def encircle(x,y, **kw):   #Convex Hull 
    ax
    p = np.c_[x,y]
    hull = ConvexHull(p)
    poly = plt.Polygon(p[hull.vertices,:])
    ax.add_patch(poly)


def animate(i) :
    scatterN.set_offsets([[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[visuals[0][0+i][0], visuals[1][0+i][0]], [visuals[0][0+i][1], visuals[1][0+i][1]], [visuals[0][0+i][2], visuals[1][0+i][2]], [visuals[0][0+i][3], visuals[1][0+i][3]], [visuals[0][0+i][4], visuals[1][0+i][4]],[visuals[0][0+i][5], visuals[1][0+i][5]], [visuals[0][0+i][6], visuals[1][0+i][6]], [visuals[0][0+i][7], visuals[1][0+i][7]], [visuals[0][0+i][8], visuals[1][0+i][8]], [visuals[0][0+i][9], visuals[1][0+i][9]], [visuals[0][0+i][10], visuals[1][0+i][10]], [visuals[0][0+i][11], visuals[1][0+i][11]], [visuals[0][0+i][12], visuals[1][0+i][12]], [visuals[0][0+i][13], visuals[1][0+i][13]], [visuals[0][0+i][14], visuals[1][0+i][14]], [visuals[0][0+i][15], visuals[1][0+i][15]], [visuals[0][0+i][16], visuals[1][0+i][16]], [visuals[0][0+i][17], visuals[1][0+i][17]], [visuals[0][0+i][18], visuals[1][0+i][18]], [visuals[0][0+i][19], visuals[1][0+i][19]], [visuals[0][0+i][20], visuals[1][0+i][20]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] )
    X = visuals[0][0+i]
    Y = visuals[1][0+i] 
    encircle(X, Y, ec="black", fc="gray", alpha=0.1)  #Convex Hull 


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,61100),
                          interval = 50, blit = False)

'''AFL Ground (Etihad Dimensions)'''


plt.style.use('ggplot')

#fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)
#ax.set_aspect('equal')

CC_xy = 0,70
GS1_xy = 75.3,67.5
GS2_xy = -84.2,67.5
F50_1_xy = -67.5, 70
F50_2_xy = 67.5, 70
angle = math.degrees(math.acos(5.5/9.15))
CS_xy = -25,45
E_xy = 0,67.5
E_xy_Freo = 0, 70

Halfway = mpl.lines.Line2D((0,0), (65,75), color = 'white', lw = 1.5, alpha = 0.2, zorder = 0.1)
Centre_Circle = mpl.patches.Circle(CC_xy, radius = 1.5, color = 'white', lw = 1.5, fill = False)
Centre_Circle_2 = mpl.patches.Circle(CC_xy, radius = 5, color = 'white', lw = 1.5, fill = False)
GS1 = mpl.patches.Rectangle(GS1_xy, 9, 6.4, color = 'white', lw = 1.5, fill = False)
GS2 = mpl.patches.Rectangle(GS2_xy, 9, 6.4, color = 'white', lw = 1.5, fill = False)
F50_1 = mpl.patches.Arc(F50_1_xy, 65, 135, angle = 0, theta2 = angle, theta1 = 360-angle, color = 'white', lw = 2)
F50_2 = mpl.patches.Arc(F50_2_xy, 65, 135, angle = 0, theta2 = 180+angle, theta1 = 180-angle, color = 'white', lw = 2)
Centre_Square = mpl.patches.Rectangle(CS_xy, 50, 50, lw = 2, color = 'white', fill = False)


Etihad_Freo = mpl.patches.Ellipse(E_xy_Freo, 168.47, 130.47, lw = 3, color = 'green', alpha = 0.1, zorder = 5)

ax.add_line(Halfway)
ax.add_patch(Centre_Circle)
ax.add_patch(Centre_Circle_2)
ax.add_patch(GS1)
ax.add_patch(GS2)
ax.add_patch(F50_1)
ax.add_patch(F50_2)
ax.add_patch(Centre_Square)
ax.add_patch(Etihad_Freo)


#ax.annotate('D50', xy = (35.5, 80), color = 'white', rotation = -75, alpha = 0.5)
#ax.annotate('D50', xy = (37, -80), color = 'white', rotation = -110, alpha = 0.5)
#ax.annotate('F50', xy = (28.5, -40), color = 'white', rotation = 110, alpha = 0.5)
#ax.annotate('F50', xy = (28, 40), color = 'white', rotation = 72, alpha = 0.5)


ax.autoscale()

plt.draw()


#plt.savefig('fill_between scatter.png', dpi = 300)
```

Comment: Your code cannot be run as such, because the csv file is not available. It is always better to post your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This can be achieved, for instance, by generating random data using `numpy.random` or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the old patch from `ax`. If you replace your `encircle` function with this, everything should be working fine:

```
def encircle(x,y, **kw):   #Convex Hull 
    ##remove old patch:
    try:
        last_patch = ax.patches[-1]
        last_patch.remove()
    except IndexError:
        pass

    ##do the other stuff
    p = np.c_[x,y]
    hull = ConvexHull(p)
    poly = plt.Polygon(p[hull.vertices,:])
    ax.add_patch(poly)
```

The `try-except` block is needed because during the first call to encircle, `ax.patches` is still empty. You could of course replace it with an `if` clause to test whether `ax.patches` is empty. Note, that this code assumes that there are no other patches in your `Axes` instance. If that would be the case, you would have to keep track of your polygons yourself. The `poly.remove()` functionality would still work. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

Here a full example based on the OP's question, but with the `csv` data replaced by `numpy.random` points.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib as mpl

N=20

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))


X = np.random.normal(1,1,N)
Y = np.random.normal(1,1,N)
scatterN = ax.scatter(X, Y, zorder = 2)   #Scatter Plot

to_be_deleted = []
def encircle(x,y, **kw):   #Convex Hull 
    ##removing old patches:
    for patch in to_be_deleted:
        patch.remove()
    del to_be_deleted[:]

    p = np.c_[x,y]
    hull = ConvexHull(p)
    poly = plt.Polygon(p[hull.vertices,:])
    ##saving new reference
    to_be_deleted.append(poly)


    ax.add_patch(poly)


def animate(i) :
    X = np.random.normal(0,50,N)
    Y = np.random.normal(70,30,N)
    scatterN.set_offsets(np.array([X,Y]).T)
    encircle(X, Y, ec="black", fc="gray", alpha=0.1, zorder = 100)  #Convex Hull 


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,61100),
                          interval = 50, blit = False)

'''AFL Ground (Etihad Dimensions)'''


plt.style.use('ggplot')

#fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)
#ax.set_aspect('equal')

CC_xy = 0,70
GS1_xy = 75.3,67.5
GS2_xy = -84.2,67.5
F50_1_xy = -67.5, 70
F50_2_xy = 67.5, 70
#angle = math.degrees(math.acos(5.5/9.15))
angle = np.degrees(np.arccos(5.5/9.15))
CS_xy = -25,45
E_xy = 0,67.5
E_xy_Freo = 0, 70

Halfway = mpl.lines.Line2D((0,0), (65,75), color = 'white', lw = 1.5, alpha = 0.2, zorder = 0.1)
Centre_Circle = mpl.patches.Circle(CC_xy, radius = 1.5, color = 'white', lw = 1.5, fill = False)
Centre_Circle_2 = mpl.patches.Circle(CC_xy, radius = 5, color = 'white', lw = 1.5, fill = False)
GS1 = mpl.patches.Rectangle(GS1_xy, 9, 6.4, color = 'white', lw = 1.5, fill = False)
GS2 = mpl.patches.Rectangle(GS2_xy, 9, 6.4, color = 'white', lw = 1.5, fill = False)
F50_1 = mpl.patches.Arc(F50_1_xy, 65, 135, angle = 0, theta2 = angle, theta1 = 360-angle, color = 'white', lw = 2)
F50_2 = mpl.patches.Arc(F50_2_xy, 65, 135, angle = 0, theta2 = 180+angle, theta1 = 180-angle, color = 'white', lw = 2)
Centre_Square = mpl.patches.Rectangle(CS_xy, 50, 50, lw = 2, color = 'white', fill = False)


Etihad_Freo = mpl.patches.Ellipse(E_xy_Freo, 168.47, 130.47, lw = 3, color = 'green', alpha = 0.1, zorder = 5)

ax.add_line(Halfway)
ax.add_patch(Centre_Circle)
ax.add_patch(Centre_Circle_2)
ax.add_patch(GS1)
ax.add_patch(GS2)
ax.add_patch(F50_1)
ax.add_patch(F50_2)
ax.add_patch(Centre_Square)
ax.add_patch(Etihad_Freo)


#ax.annotate('D50', xy = (35.5, 80), color = 'white', rotation = -75, alpha = 0.5)
#ax.annotate('D50', xy = (37, -80), color = 'white', rotation = -110, alpha = 0.5)
#ax.annotate('F50', xy = (28.5, -40), color = 'white', rotation = 110, alpha = 0.5)
#ax.annotate('F50', xy = (28, 40), color = 'white', rotation = 72, alpha = 0.5)


ax.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'll keep that in mind for next time. This works well.

Comment: I do have further `ax.patches` to plot specific axis limits. How would the `poly.remove()` function work in this instance?

Comment: @JeremyAlexander everytime you create a `patch` or `poly` that you want to remove later, keep a reference to it (maybe in a list called `to_be_removed` or some such). Then, when it's time to remove patches, iterate through that list, call `remove()` on all the objects and empty the list (`to_be_removed = []`). For a more specific answer, I would need more specific code :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Thomas. I've added the code that contains the additional patches.